# How to erase certain names in files with Python

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I am trying to erase certain names of subfolders that were download with weird names containing useless information, (in this case, these are movie files so things like 720p, BluRay, etc.)

My code so far is this:

```
os.chdir(r"E:\Users\Lucas\HD externo\Filmes_séries_documentários\Diretores")

lista = ["1080p","720p", "BDrip", "BRRip", "Xvid", "XViD","XviD", "ETRG", "Woody Allen", "DVDRip", "avi", "x264", "AC3-JYK", "BluRay", "DC", ".....anoXmous", "EXTENDED", "pt", "BR"]

for i in range(len(os.listdir())):
    for b in os.listdir():
        os.chdir(r"E:\Users\Lucas\HD externo\Filmes_séries_documentários\Diretores\\" + os.listdir()[i])
        for c in range(len(os.listdir())):
             for item in lista:
                 if item in os.listdir()[i]:
                     a = os.listdir()[i].replace(item, "")
                     os.rename(os.listdir()[i], a)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your code does and how that is different from what you wish it did?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problems that you currently facing with your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use [os.walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) when looking through a directory structure.

If you want to remove the file, I'd use `os.remove(filename)`

```
import os

dir = r"C:\Windows\Path\"
lista = ['all','of','the','things']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for file in files:
        for part in lista:
            if part in file:
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```